# Subscribing to arxiv subsection cs

Tags: computer-science, arxiv

I want to subscribe to a subsection of arxiv in computer science. I sent a mail like:

> Subject: subscribe Name Surname
> From: name.surname@university.country
> To: cs.lo@arxiv.org
> Content: add LO

So that was some days ago and according to the subscription page I should get daily digests (none so far).

Did anyone succeed with this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but looking at the instructions [here](https://arxiv.org/help/subscribe) and the example for `q-fin`, wouldn't you need to send it to `cs@arxiv.org`, since `cs` is the archive and `LO` is the subject class/category?

Comment: I have converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(Converting my comment into an answer)</sup>

The [help page](https://arxiv.org/help/subscribe) for subscriptions refers to the [category taxonomy](https://arxiv.org/category_taxonomy) that lists all the available archives and the categories within each.

From there, and from the examples in the help page (particularly that of "q-fin"), one can see that the archive in your case is "cs", and so you need to send the email to cs@arxiv.org instead.